# NodeJS: How can I retrieve a parameter when send to a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, promise, request

I'll try to make fast and simple. 
I need to retrieve a parameter that I'm using into a promise. Here's how the code works:

```
function foo(param) {
 return fromPromise(blabla, blabla2, param)
  .then((res) => {
   return res
  }).catch((error) => {
   console.log('Oh snap!', error);
  });
```

How do I get the param to become part of the 'res'? I'm not sure I'm clear enough... and if more info is needed let me know. 
I mean in that case I put a return res into the then but you can put anything you want in there, I just need the result of 'fromPromise' to include 'param' in some way.
FYI: In my code, the fromPromise is a request-promise and it looks like:

```
function fromPromise(blabla, blabla2, param) {
 return rp({
  url: `www.someUrl.com/${blabla2}/${param}
  json: true,
 }).then((data) => {
  return data
 }).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Oh snap!', error);
 });
```

And each function has its own module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just use the parameter.  Learn about closures.

Comment: Also, `promise.then(data => data)` doesn't really make sense. You aren't specifying anything to be done with the result of the promise.

Comment: Also, your `catch()` handlers are completely wrong; don't hide errors from the caller.  Only catch an error if you know what to do with it.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-06-10/advanced-promise-usage/

Comment: Hey Guys! Thanks for your feedbacks... From what I understand @SLaks it's not possible to get the parameter back. I'll try to learn more about closures.

Comment: As for your question @csander I'm actually making a bunch of modifications along the way. I have the request promise, which is just a request to a server and passes an array of params, then I get the response back, modify it and write it into a JSON file. My goal was to include the param's name within the response or its modification and get it in the file...

Comment: @Ardzii: That's exactly the opposite of how this works.  Parameters are automatically available inside nested callbacks; this is called a closure.

Comment: @SLaks, I edited the code posted in the question. Is it better now with the error being specified?

Comment: @Ardzii: No; you're still hiding the error from the caller.  Don't do that.

Comment: @SLaks: OK, I won't do that... I'll try find out what I'm doing wrong reading from your blog and correct once I understand what is it I'm doing doing wrong. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're asking you can do this.

```
function foo(param) { //This creates a closure and param is available to functions created with in it. 
    return fromPromise(blabla, blabla2, param)
        .then((res) => {
            res.param = param; //param is available through the closeure.
            return res;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Oh snap!');
        });
}
```

Or maybe you're trying to do it from that second function?

```
function fromPromise(blabla, blabla2, param) {//This creates a closure and param is available to functions created with in it.
    return rp({
        url: `www.someUrl.com/${blabla2}/${param}
        json: true
    })
    .then((data) => {
        data.param = param;//param is available through the closeure.
        return data;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Oh snap!', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey Jerinaw! It would be something like that but unfortunately, the params is not nested, nor mentioned within the 'res'. It's only being used as a parameter for the request promise which ultimately returns the response...

Comment: I think you should read up on closures as mentioned. I'll add some comments maybe it'll clear things up.

Comment: Hey! I got the closure thing! Thanks Jerinaw & the others!

Answer (score 1):

When chaining promise(s) , then function accepts only one parameter. What we do is use object destruction and construction introduced in ES6 to propagate more than 1 parameters

```
function A(x , y) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)->{
       return resolve({x, y}) //NOTE the object construction here
   });
}

function B() {
   return A(1, 2).then(({x, y})-> { //NOTE object destructio
      console.log(x);
      console.log(y)
   })
}
```

[More on ES6 object destruction](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

Comment: Hey Sahan! That could actually solve my problem! Let me see how I can apply it... In my case, and adapting to your example, my objective is to the actual resolve from x which could be say: z and keep y for the next level...
Such that function B has .then(someOtherFunction({z, y}).